# How can I implement something like Play Store Description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Play Store (among so many other websites) shows the description of the item not completely, instead they show part of it, and it hides the rest.

You can click on "Read More" in order to get to read the rest of the description, which (the button) will expand the description part.

The thing is: It show the rest of the text as faded just like you can see here:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider&hl=en

Please notice the text "**to bump into something you know.**"

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Here we expect you to research (eg via google), try any tutorials you find... and only come to us with a question when you've at least had a go yourself. so, give it a bash - even if you can't do all of it, at least have a go at the bits you know how to solve. The show us the code you've tried (even if it isn't working) and we can help you fill in the blanks.

Comment: Hello Taryn, Thanks for your -1, I have really hard searched the internet, even tried to get the code from the Play Store and even tried various searches like having a transparant image under the text being shown when the text overflows... Just after almost searching a log I have posted here. Sorry to bother again, I might not be fit for Stackoverflow after all!

Comment: @xdeveloper don't worry about it! All he was saying was the standard way to approach a question on SO is by showing what you have tried first, this is so we can get your mindset and correct it if need be. We are all here to help as much as we can!

Comment: Thanks @Schultzie, I understand what you mean, and I appreciate the time and efforts of everybody here trying to help us get better. I am really an ex-developer (as my name) and that's why I really need a very big refreshing reading everything I have missed... Thanks to you guys I am able to slowly... Hoping that one day I can pay back here or at somewhere else.

Comment: @xdeveloper I did not -1 you. That was somebody else. Just giving you some ideas to go on with :) Also - if you show us the research you've done, then we don't duplicate your efforts.

Comment: @TarynEast not a problem. I started to learn how to use things like jsfiddle in order to demonstrate my ideas quickly and easily. Thanks for the reply, I appreciate your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go into `inspect element` mode in your developer tools, you'll notice that it's an absolutely positioned element, with a gradient background that transitions to transparent. By defining a set height for the description, and hiding your overflow, we can add the cool 'faded text' effect to the elements. After that it's just a simple class toggle to hide the effect and set the height of the text to 100%.

Example Below!

```js
$(function() {
  $('.read').click(function() {
    $('.text').toggleClass('expanded');
  });
});
```

```css
.text {
  height: 75px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.text.expanded {
  height: 100%;
}
.text.expanded .top {
  display: none;
}
.top {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0)), color-stop(100%, #F5F5F5));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0), #F5F5F5);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0), #F5F5F5);
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <div class="top"></div>
</div>
<a href="javscript:void(0);" class="read">Read More</a>
```